# How to pack a .bat and dependencies into a exe

Tags: batch-file, exe

I have a .bat file that opens some program in the same directory that it's in. It needs the programs and all of their data. Now is their a way for me to pack the batch file and the folders into a exe so it will all run on one click and only have to distribute one file.

Please ask for any additional information.

Comment: Well, there's [NSIS](http://nsis.sf.net/), but be prepared for a bit of a learning curve before you can get it to do what you want.

Comment: Also, look into [7-zip sfx](http://superuser.com/questions/42788/).  There's a [tutorial here](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/39048-how-to-make-a-7-zip-switchless-installer/).

Comment: check iexpress. It's built-in on every windows machine and has an UI with some options that can do the thing.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using 7-Zip SFX files. I created a writeup of this a long time ago and developed a script to make the process of creating these "self contained" packages easy:

http://www.howtogeek.com/50364/convert-a-batch-bat-script-to-an-executable-exe-file/

For example, running this command:

```
MakeExeFromBat.bat MyBatFile.bat SomeTool.exe SomeOtherBatFile.bat
```

Would produce `MyBatFile.exe` which contains both the BAT files (yours and the dependency) as well as the EXE which are available to your batch file for calls.

Upon running, the process works like this:

1. The contents of `MyBatFile.exe` are extracted to a temp directory.
2. `MyBatFile.bat` is executed and run. Any command line parameters passed are sent to `MyBatFile.bat` so you can consume them normally.
3. Once finished, the temp directory is cleaned up.

Because this processing is done by the SFX, a few important notices regarding the limitations of this need to be mentioned (I am not aware of a tool or workaround which can overcome these limitations):

- Once the EXE file is run, it will be processed in a new command window - not the current one. This means your script will not have any knowledge of the current `cmd` instance unless you provide them via parameters.
- Building on the above, relative paths will not work. For example, you pass `\Subdir` as a parameter to `MyBatFile.exe` (again which opens in a new `cmd` instance) then `\Subdir` will attempt to resolve to a path in the temp structure where it was extracted. You can get around this by always providing full path names.

For the most part, however, if you aren't dealing with user provided file processing, these limitations will not come into play.

Answer (score 0):

This application seems to do what you want.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/batch-compiler/